# Как работает htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php

В документации написано, что функция преобразует символы в HTML сущности.

Как это понимать?

Comment: Там же дальше еще много чего написано. Что там непонятного, вроде все достаточно понятно.

Answer (score 4):

`htmlspecialchars` является достаточно полезной функцией в PHP.

Бывают ситуации, когда становится необходимым вывести что-то в проекте для отображения.
Представим ситуацию, что надо вывести ссылку на определённый ресурс через PHP.
В этом случае Вы используете вывод данных через:

```
echo = "<div><a href='https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'>Stackoverflow</a></div>";
```

или:

```
print_r("<div><a href='https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'>Stackoverflow</a></div>");
```

В обоих этих случаях вывод данных выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае, теги HTML преобразуются и мы видим только их результат, а именно ссылку.

### Иногда бывает необходимость вывести данные вместе с самой разметкой HTML.

В этом случае мы и используем функцию `htmlspecialchars`.
Она помогает преобразовать символы разметки в код, который можно отобразить, не выполняя эту часть разметки.

К примеру, делая запись таким способом:

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<div><a href='https://ru.stackoverflow.com/'>Stackoverflow</a></div>", ENT_QUOTES);
print_r($new);
```

Увидите вывод данных с теми метками, которые были указаны:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, данные выводятся ровно в том виде, в котором они записаны, без преобразования тегов HTML.

Если чуть подробнее, то преобразуются данные подобным образом:

> '&' (амперсанд) преобразуется в '&'
>
> '"' (двойная кавычка) преобразуется в '"' when ENT_NOQUOTES is
>   not set.
>
> ''' (одиночная кавычка) преобразуется в ''' только в режиме
>   ENT_QUOTES.
>
> '<' (знак "меньше чем") преобразуется в '<'
>
> '>' (знак "больше чем") преобразуется в '>'

Так же данная функция имеет несколько параметров для преобразования.
Это могут быть кодировки, разница ковычек и так далее.

Для более подробной информации - [офф. мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: Спасибо большое, наконец-то разобрался

Answer (score 1):

`htmlspecialchars` преобразует html-код в текст.

Например:

было: **Hello**
стало: <.b>Hello<./b> (без точек)

Comment: html-код тоже является текстом по определению, так что ваш ответ бессмысленен